# gtkmm: add widgets that are not fields of class

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm

I would like to add to gtkmm widgets that are not fields of class (I declare them in method).

I tried this:

```cpp
class MyWidget : public Gtk::Window {
public:
    MyWidget();
    virtual MyWidget();
}

MyWidget::MyWidget() {
    Gtk::Label label("my label");
    add(label);
    label.show();
}
```

But it does not shwo anthing.

But when i declare label in class and extend method by it, it works:

```cpp
class MyWidget : public Gtk::Window {
public:
    MyWidget();
    virtual MyWidget();
protected:
    Gtk::Label label;
}

MyWidget::MyWidget() : label("my label") {
    add(label);
    label.show();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

A widget created in such way is destroyed with the closing bracket of the method. Please read [this tutorial about memory management](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-memory-widgets.html.en).

Personally I'd propose using [dynamic allocation with make_managed() and add()](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-memory-widgets.html.en#memory-managed-dynamic). It's very easy to use and I have never had any problems when using that.

```
MyWidget::MyWidget() {
  auto* label = Gtk::make_managed<Gtk::Label>("my label");
  add(*label);
  label->show();
}
```

Comment: Better answer since it gives an alternative.